# get direction vector from btScalar matrix

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, matrix, bullet

I have created a bullet vehicle with a compound as the chassis and the compound is formed of 2 bodies, a chassis and a turret.

I can obtain the turret transform and opengl matrix like this:

```
// get chassis and turret transforms
btTransform chassisTransform = m_vehicle->getChassisWorldTransform();
btTransform turretTransform = compound->getChildTransform(1);
// multiply transforms to get updated turret transform
turretTransform *= chassisTransform;

// get turret matrix
btScalar turretMatrix[16];
turretTransform.getOpenGLMatrix(turretMatrix);
```

I am trying to get the turret forward/direction vector from this matrix. I need this so that I will have the camera fixed to the turret's position and direction.

What I have tried is this:

```
btVector3 turretForwardVector = btVector3(turretMatrix[2], turretMatrix[6], turretMatrix[9]);
```

But this doesn't give me the right vector.

Where exactly do I have to look for the vector in this matrix?

Comment: I managed to find this [link](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/175515-Get-Direction-from-Transformation-Matrix-or-Quat). It explained where I would find the direction vector in the matrix (3rd column).

So I got the 8th, 9th and 10th matrix elemets and created the turretForwardMatrix from that like this:
`btVector3 turretForwardVector = btVector3(turretMatrix[8], turretMatrix[9], turretMatrix[10]);
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is right. Extracting only a row or column vectur suffices. Right now, in OpenGL matrix notation you're extracting the Z row. I suggest you try the column, i.e. `turretMatrix[0x8 … 0xb]`

Comment: Yes, I found that the 8th, 9th and 10th matrix elements held the info I needed! Thanks